# set different ToggleButtons to change one textviewcolor on the same activity

Tags: android, android-activity, togglebutton, android-togglebutton, android-color

I am building an app with three toggle buttons. When each is pressed, it changes the textView in the same activity to three different colors. When two toggle buttons are pressed together, it changes the same textview to other colors, and when all three are pressed together, it changes the textview to white. How can i do this? i tried using switch statement, and if (isChecked), but it had errors

This is my MainActivity.java file

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ToggleButton redtoggleButton;
ToggleButton bluetoggleButton;
ToggleButton greentoggleButton;
TextView june;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    redtoggleButton=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    bluetoggleButton=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
    greentoggleButton=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);
    june=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    if (redtoggleButton.isChecked()){
  june.setTextColor(Color.RED);
  }else if (bluetoggleButton.isChecked()){
june.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
}else if (greentoggleButton.isChecked()){
june.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
}





}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

and my activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="June 2015"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="50dp" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New ToggleButton"
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textOff="Off"
        android:textOn="On" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New ToggleButton"
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textOff="Off"
        android:textOn="On"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New ToggleButton"
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textOff="Off"
        android:textOn="On"/>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reset"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minWidth="150dp"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minHeight="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Top Rated"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:minWidth="160dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="137dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Random"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:minWidth="160dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

please help
any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please post the complete code that you tried along with the logcat with errors. The code you have provided does not contain any logic related to the functionality that you want to achieve.

Comment: it didn't give any errors, it just did not work. i tried a couple of things but this is the last one i tried

Comment: @Aria Hi there again! Check my answer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your whole code with this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ToggleButton redtoggleButton;
    ToggleButton bluetoggleButton;
    ToggleButton greentoggleButton;
    TextView june;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        redtoggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        bluetoggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
        greentoggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);
        june = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        redtoggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                changeTextColor();
            }
        });

        bluetoggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                changeTextColor();
            }
        });

        greentoggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                changeTextColor();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        changeTextColor();
    }

    public void changeTextColor() {
        boolean redToggle = redtoggleButton.isChecked();
        boolean greenToggle = greentoggleButton.isChecked();
        boolean blueToggle = bluetoggleButton.isChecked();

        int redValue;
        int greenValue;
        int blueValue;

        if (redToggle) {
            redValue = 255;
        } else {
            redValue = 0;
        }

        if (greenToggle) {
            greenValue = 255;
        } else {
            greenValue = 0;
        }

        if (blueToggle) {
            blueValue = 255;
        } else {
            blueValue = 0;
        }

        june.setTextColor(Color.rgb(redValue, greenValue, blueValue));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: it works but for only one toggle button at a time. Plus it is all on one activity, can shared preferences be used in just one activity?

Comment: @Aria I think you tested my answer before I have updated it. You are right, it was only working for only one ToggleButton. But I have updated it afterwards. It now works with 9 different colors and with much less code. I really recommend you to test my updated answer too. It's the most logical one. Tell me when you test it please. :)

Comment: I have only added SharedPreferences to save the values, so that these values are loaded again when reopenning the app. You can certainly remove the SharedPreferences, if you don't want to save the values.

Comment: yes! it works even better than mine! thank you again

Comment: No problem. Happy to help! :)

Comment: how can i take off the shared preferences?

Comment: @Aria Updated my answer. Check it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `OnCheckedChangedListener` to your toggle buttons. The code in onCheckedChanged will then always be executed when you toggle one of the buttons.

```
int red = 0;
int blue = 0;
int green = 0;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    redtoggleButton=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    bluetoggleButton=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
    greentoggleButton=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);
    june=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    redtoggleButton.addOnCheckedChangedListener(toggleListener);
    bluetoggleButton.addOnCheckedChangedListener(toggleListener);
    greentoggleButton.addOnCheckedChangedListener(toggleListener);
}

private OnCheckedChangedListener toggleListener = new OnCheckedChangedListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        red = redtoggleButton.isChecked() ? 255 : 0;
        blue = bluetoggleButton.isChecked() ? 255 : 0;
        green = greentoggleButton.isChecked() ? 255 : 0;
        if (redtoggleButton.isChecked() && bluetoggleButton.isChecked() 
            && greentoggleButton.isChecked()) {
            june.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        } else {
            june.setTextColor(Color.rgb(red,blue,green));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `OnCheckedChangeListener` on your buttons. Try this:

```
redtoggleButton=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
bluetoggleButton=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
greentoggleButton=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);
june=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

redtoggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        changeColor();
    }
});

bluetoggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        changeColor();
    }
});

greentoggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        changeColor();
    }
});

public void changeColor()
{
   if (redtoggleButton.isChecked())
       june.setTextColor(Color.RED);

   else if (bluetoggleButton.isChecked())
       june.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

   else if (greentoggleButton.isChecked())
       june.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

Check [Official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html) for more inforfation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out.
MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import static android.graphics.Color.*;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ToggleButton redtoggleButton;
ToggleButton bluetoggleButton;
ToggleButton greentoggleButton;
TextView june;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    redtoggleButton=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    bluetoggleButton=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
    greentoggleButton=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);
    june=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    redtoggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                if (!bluetoggleButton.isChecked()&& !greentoggleButton.isChecked()) {
                    june.setTextColor(RED);
                }else if (bluetoggleButton.isChecked()&&!greentoggleButton.isChecked()) {
                    june.setTextColor(MAGENTA);
                }else if (!bluetoggleButton.isChecked()&&greentoggleButton.isChecked()){
                    june.setTextColor(YELLOW);
                }else if (bluetoggleButton.isChecked()&&greentoggleButton.isChecked()){
                    june.setTextColor(WHITE);
                }

            }else june.setTextColor(BLACK);
        }
    });
    bluetoggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                if(!redtoggleButton.isChecked()&&!greentoggleButton.isChecked()){
                    june.setTextColor(BLUE);
                }else if (redtoggleButton.isChecked()&&!greentoggleButton.isChecked()){
                    june.setTextColor(MAGENTA);
                }else if (!redtoggleButton.isChecked()&&greentoggleButton.isChecked()){
                    june.setTextColor(CYAN);
                }else if (redtoggleButton.isChecked()&&greentoggleButton.isChecked()){
                    june.setTextColor(WHITE);
                }
            }else june.setTextColor(BLACK);
        }
    });
    greentoggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                if(!bluetoggleButton.isChecked()&&!redtoggleButton.isChecked()){
                    june.setTextColor(GREEN);
                }else if (bluetoggleButton.isChecked()&&!redtoggleButton.isChecked()){
                    june.setTextColor(CYAN);
                }else if (!bluetoggleButton.isChecked()&&redtoggleButton.isChecked()){
                    june.setTextColor(YELLOW);
                }else if (bluetoggleButton.isChecked()&&redtoggleButton.isChecked()){
                    june.setTextColor(WHITE);
                }
            }else june.setTextColor(BLACK);
        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="June 2015"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="50dp" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New ToggleButton"
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textOff="Off"
        android:textOn="On" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New ToggleButton"
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textOff="Off"
        android:textOn="On"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New ToggleButton"
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textOff="Off"
        android:textOn="On"/>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reset"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minWidth="150dp"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minHeight="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Top Rated"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:minWidth="160dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="137dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Random"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:minWidth="160dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

thanks for the help, everyone :)